# Secure way to store API token in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, terraform

I am working on this small `terraform` project that uses `gcp` (google cloud platform) `token.json` which contains secure credentials to create resources.

Terraform files are executed by the Gitlab CI/CD.

My concern is, this `token.json` is used by the one of the `terraform` files (main.tf) as below.

```
# Configure the backend
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {
    bucket      = "tf_backend_gcp_banuka_jana_jayarathna_k8s"
    prefix      = "terraform/gcp/boilerplate"
    credentials = "./token.json" ----> file I need to keep securely
  }
}
```

This `token.json` is in the root folder with the `main.tf` file above.

This file is needed for that file and I can't think of any other way how I can store this. This token cannot even put to `gitlab` variables as there is no way to pass the values of the token to this `main.tf` file when the pipeline runs.

I don't want to expose the `token.json` to public too. Is there a way I can achieve this in `Gitlab`?
Can't even use a tool like `git-crypt` because then how can I decrypt this `token.json` and feed it to the `main.tf`...

Is there a way to inject variables to `terraform` files ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can base64 encode the file and put it into a GitLab CI variable.

```
cat token.json | base64
```

And then you can decode it and create the file before you run terraform apply

```
terraform-apply:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo $GCE_TOKEN | base64 -d > token.json
    - terraform apply
```

Comment: So, how can I integrate this decoded token to the `backend` configuration in `terraform` ?

Comment: I updated my post with a GitLab CI snippet. You already have your backend pointing to the file *token.json* so terraform should pick it up from the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

- Store the token as a variable in GitLab (Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables), make sure to enable masking.
- Define a variable for the token in your terraform manifests.
- Supply the token variable to terraform when you run apply.

variables.tf

```
variable "gce_token" {
  type = string
}
```

main.tf

```
  terraform {
    backend "gcs" {
      bucket      = "tf_backend_gcp_banuka_jana_jayarathna_k8s"
      prefix      = "terraform/gcp/boilerplate"
      credentials = var.gce_token
    }
  }
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
  terraform apply -var="gce_token=$GCE_TOKEN"
```

Comment: Your approach is good, but terraform doesn't allow to use variables for `backend`

Comment: I forgot about that, posted another solution that I think will work.

Answer (score 0):

After a while, when I was working on the same thing, I encounter the same problem and I found a solution.

We can put `AWS` `access-key` and `secret-key` in `Gitlab` CI Variables and we can export them before `terraform init` or `terraform apply` or any terraform command:

```
  before_script:
    - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${access_key}
    - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${secrect_key}
```